# ¿Cómo un parámetro puede leer más de un valor?

Tags: sql-server

Intento que un parámetro lea todas las máquinas que se encuentran en una tabla,
pero me sigue saliendo un error que no puede tener más de un valor a la vez,
he intentado con coalesce y con split, pero me sigue leyendo solo un valor de la tabla.

```
SELECT  @JOBNO = JOBNO FROM PMMASTER as pm INNER JOIN LABORMP as lab
        ON pm.PMID = lab.PMID INNER JOIN PMMSCHEDULE ps
        ON pm.PMID = ps.PMID 
        where ps.CYCLETYPE =2 and ps.SETTING2 IS NOT NULL and ps.SETTING1 IS NOT NULL
```

Para poder aplicar el ciclo para saber las siguientes fechas de su mantenimiento.

```
IF(@Result <@FechaHasta)

            SELECT  @Result =   DATEADD(day,    @Setting1,  @Result)
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [00TblFecha] ON 

            INSERT INTO dbo.[00TblFecha](idFecha,jobno,fecha)VALUES(4,@JOBNO,@Result)

            SET IDENTITY_INSERT[00TblFecha] OFF     
            print @Result
```

Comment: Cuál es tu objetivo final?, porque te sigue lanzando ese error porque una variable puede tener un solo valor a la vez

Comment: Danos un ejemplo de la data que tienes y el resultado esperado, con eso seguramente te podremos dar mejores ideas.

Comment: Quiero aplicarle un ciclo, a todas las maquinas para saber cuando sera su proximo mantenimiento, hace el ciclo, todo bien pero solo lee una maquina y solo me da la fecha de esa maquina obviamente, pero necesito saber las fechas de todas las maquinas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realizas una query que asigna una variable es logico que unicamente asignara un valor simple.

Para recorrer varios deberias crear un `cursor`, usarias el

[DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169(v=sql.110).aspx)

DECLARE @JOBNO VARCHAR(100)

```
DECLARE maquinas_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT JOBNO FROM PMMASTER as pm INNER JOIN LABORMP as lab
    ON pm.PMID = lab.PMID INNER JOIN PMMSCHEDULE ps
    ON pm.PMID = ps.PMID 
    where ps.CYCLETYPE =2 and ps.SETTING2 IS NOT NULL and ps.SETTING1 IS NOT NULL

OPEN maquinas_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM maquinas_cursor INTO @JOBNO

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN   

    -- aqui trabajas con el dato de la variable

    -- tomas el proximo valor
    FETCH NEXT FROM maquinas_cursor INTO @JOBNO

END 

CLOSE maquinas_cursor
DEALLOCATE maquinas_cursor
```

una vez declardo el cursor con los datos poder usar el WHILE para iterar

[Cursores en Transact SQL](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/240/Cursores-en-Transact-SQL.aspx)